# Script for root to git pull as another user

Tags: linux, git, bash, ubuntu

I have a script that I would like to have do a git pull inside another user's git directory.  This script is run by the root user.  For example:

```
cd /home/username/GitProject
sudo -u username -i git pull
```

When I run this, I get:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Is there a way to have my script do a git pull as `username`?

Comment: Try replacing `git pull` with `pwd` and see what it prints.

Comment: I get `/home/username`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try without the `-i` option to sudo.  That option is documented as first changing to the target user's home directory, which undoes the directory change you so carefully do before that.  Alternatively, use the appropriate options to git to specify the directory, something like this:

```
sudo -u username -i git --git-dir=/home/username/GitProject/.git --work-tree=/home/username/GitProject pull
```

Comment: I added the additional git params.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without sudo. This assumes you have password-less ssh keys since you are talking about a script. Here's the failure:

```
# git clone <user>@<host>:/path/to/repo
Cloning into 'repo'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This shows that `~` properly expands to the user's homedir:

```
# MYUSER=somebody
# su - $MYUSER -c "echo ~"
/home/somebody
```

And here's the actual command used to clone into the home directory along with some extra proofs:

```
# su - $MYUSER -c "git clone <user>@<host>:/path/to/repo"
Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: Counting objects: 13, done.
<..>

# ls -l /home/$MYUSER/repo/.git/config
-rw-r--r-- 1 somebody somebody 275 Nov  8 23:55 /home/somebody/repo/.git/config

# su - $MYUSER -c "cd ~/repo; git remote -v"
origin <user>@<host>:/path/to/repo (fetch)
origin <user>@<host>:/path/to/repo (push)

# su - $MYUSER -c "cd ~/repo; git pull"
Already up-to-date.
```